# Correctness of equation for $\sum_{n} n!^s$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

It's possible, that equation $\sum_{n} n!^s=1+2\sum_n (2n+1)!^s$ is correct for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$ with which sum $\sum_{n} n!^s$ is convergent?

I'm looking for closed formula of that sum and correctness of that equation  is very important to me. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that your sums run over the nonnegative integers,

$$\sum_{n \ge 0} n!^s$$

is convergent if and only if $s < 0$. (Apply the ratio test.)

It's easy to evaluate both sides at $s = -1$. In that case, the left-hand side is just

$$ \sum_{n \ge 0} {1 \over n!} = e$$

and the left-hand side is $1 + 2 \sinh 1$, where $\sinh$ is the hyperbolic sine. In particular, the sum $\sum_{n \ge 0} 1/(2n+1)!$ is greater than 1 (the $n=1$ term is 1), and so $1 + 2\sum_{n \ge 0} 1/(2n+1)! > 3$.  So the identity you want to prove is false.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I found big mistake in my calculations... :-/

Answer (score 3):

write $A(s)=\sum_{n} n!^s$ and $B(s)=1+2\sum_n (2n+1)!^s$.  Numerically we get
$$
\lim_{s\to-\infty}\frac{A(s)}{B(s)} = \frac{2}{3}
$$
another evidence that they are not identically equal...

Other numerical evidence suggests:
$$
\lim_{s\to-\infty} B(s)-A(s) = 1;\qquad
\lim_{s\to0-} B(s)-A(s) = \frac{1}{2}.
$$